# Eclipse plugin dev: how to add default VM arguments by code?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

While developing some plugins based on Eclipse, I need to add some default VM arguments when user right click-> "run as" -> "java application" or "spring boot app", is there any open api I can call or any extension point?
Just like the snapshot below, the argument "-Daaa=bbb" is added by default.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need to modify the `ILaunchConfiguration`. See [Program debug and launch support](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own plugin and need to replicate/extend Java launch configuration
(of type Java application) from JDT and add `-vm` argument programmatically.

But there is one more easy way: Try **LcDsl**.

> LcDsl provides a way of defining Eclipse launch configurations in a textual way. The file extension used is '.lc' It provides some obvious and some non-obvious advantages over the Eclipse launch configuration solution.

For more info look [here](https://github.com/mduft/lcdsl) and check demo videos. Also there was a discussion going on to include this plugin in JDT itself, see this bug [entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513735).

A typical Java launch configuration looks like this:

```
java configuration LcJavaMain {
    project com.wamas.test;
    main-class com.wamas.test.JavaMain;

    memory min=64m max=256m;

    vm-argument '-Dmy.arg=value';
    argument 'cmdArg';
}
```